# try to delete the file from svn using AnkSvn with visual studio2010

Tags: file, svn

I am using SVN with Visual Studio2010 having AnkSvn to communicate with SVN.
when I try to delete a specific file it throws error :

> cannot verify lock  the path filename no matching lock-token
>   available

here is my version details:

> svn-version=1.7.6  os-version=6.1.7601.65536
>   `ankh-version=2.4.11610.27`

Any Help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I solved this issue actually after installing the trotoise svn it gives more control on directory and files.
Trotoise SVN has option to release the lock,it helps me solve this issue.

RightClick->TrotoiseSVN->Release Lock

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the file is in read-only mode.

Comment: Thanks! yeah! I have checked it , but luckily it solves by installing trotoise svn its gives more command on windows explorer. I checked with the trotoise svn and release lock then it solve :)